# monit Sendmail: Cannot switch to SSL

Tags: email-server, monit

I setup monit to monitor some services which are running on my servers. On one of the servers I also have a mail server running, which handles the mail transport for the domains I own (in this case for example example.com). For a long time, monit was configured to send an e-mail to my e-mail address (myname@example.com) whenever a service does not respond anymore.

Now, since some time (I unfortunately don't know when exactly), monit does not send an e-mail anymore. In my logs I found lines something like this:

```
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] debug    : Processing postponed events queue
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] debug    : monit: processing queued event /var/lib/monit/events/1476176912_a2e860
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] debug    : Timestamp failed notification is sent to myname@example.com
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] error    : monit: Cannot get the SSL server certificate!
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] error    : Sendmail: Cannot switch to SSL
[CEST Oct 11 11:10:50] error    : Alert handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle
```

(debug log enabled)

The configuration of the mailserver in the monitrc file looks like:

```
set mailserver bits.example.com port 587 username "monit@example.com" password "secret" using tlsv1 with timeout 30 seconds
```

As I haven't changed anything, and the configuration in monit looks good to me, I thought my mail server does not work like expected anymore (even if I haven't found any problem with other users of the server (some web projects)). However, I tried to send an e-mail directly using openssl (as the server allows tls connections only):

```
myuser@server:~$ openssl s_client -connect bits.example.com:587 -starttls smtp -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = StartCom Certification Authority, CN = StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = bits.example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=bits.example.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=StartCom Certification Authority/CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=StartCom Certification Authority/CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<removed for a shorter code snippet>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=bits.example.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=StartCom Certification Authority/CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3485 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 0B22EB3DDF1E0693E4A6152CEF26206572185112A7C9353397BFADAB5CB552E0
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 29348D1D2EC0819321B1B98C910EB9737BEF54699998ACD2BCB5687D22ED320F42E086D2B263A7DB82661C56AE7A6235
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1476177537
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 DSN
EHLO bits.example.com
250-example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 51200000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM:monit@example.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:myuser@example.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Test mail

This is a test.

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 50C965FAE9
QUIT
DONE
```

and like you see it works fine. So now I'm at the end of my knowledge :( Why can't monit send an e-mail using my own e-mail server anymore. Does anyone has an idea what the problem is? If I need to provide more information, feel free to ask! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your monit config explicitly chooses to use the mail submission port (587) but your manual test used port 25. Either test again against port 587 or change the monit config to use 25 and then update question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: I changed the question, as postfix listens on 587 and 25, both works fine. However, I tested the sending again with 587 as a port. Just for the record: In monit's config I supplied a username and password. However, postfix currently doesn't require a username password for sending (permit_mynetworks), which will change in the next time (that's why monit already has a username/password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading monit from 5.6 (shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 apt sources) to 5.20 (latest release, manual upgrade) sending mails works without any problems again. The configuration was not changed so far, so this looks really like a bug in the older version of monit.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Monit 5.26.0, I was trying to get Monit to send mail with Mailgun and the reason it wasn't working was `tlsv1` should have been `tls`. According to [this wiki page](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Gmail), monit 5.17 or later should use `tls` with Gmail or similar email providers.

Comment: Wow! I just had to login and say THANK YOU! This worked after I tried everything from iptable ports, router port tests, different monit settings... THANKS!!!